# hi why does my else in while loop is not working?

Tags: python, while-loop

I wanted to select two numbers and when I run the program it will start form the lower one and will print me numbers one after one till the big number.
the loop in the while is working but the else doesnt work...

```
num1= int(input('enter first number'))    
num2= int (input('enter second number'))

while num1 > num2 :
    print(num2)
    num2= num2 + 1

else:
 
    print(num1)
    num1 = num1 + 1
```

I wanted to select two numbers and when I run the program it will start form the lower one and will print me numbers one after one till the big number.
the loop in the while is working but the else doesnt work...

Comment: I'm not clear what you want this to do - I tested it, and it is running the code in the `else` block after `num2` becomes greater than or equal to `num1`. This looks like it's doing exactly what you describe already?

Comment: Okay, I thing I figured out what you're looking for. Robotuser's answer below will work, but you should understand that the `else` block is only evaluated *once*, nomatter how many times the condition is checked. As soon as the condition (`num1 > num2`) evaluates as false once, the else block will run and the program will continue. Note that if it continued running the `else` block every iteration, it would never stop - the condition becoming false is how the `while` loop knows to exit.

Answer (score -1):

You haven't written **If statement** in your code that,s why its not working

Comment: Python has `while... else` constructs

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).